# How to efficiently match regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a code to match the US phone number format

So it should match:

```
123-333-1111
(123)111-2222
123-2221111
```

But should not match 
    1232221111

```
matchThreeDigits = r"(?:\s*\(?[\d]{3}\)?\s*)"
matchFourDigits = r"(?:\s*[\d]{4}\s*)"
phoneRegex = '('+ '('+  matchThreeDigits + ')' + '-?' +   '('+  matchThreeDigits + ')' + '-?' + '(' + matchFourDigits + ')' +')';
matches = re.findall(re.compile(phoneRegex),line)
```

The problem is I need to make sure at least one of () or '-' is present in present in the  pattern (or else it can be a nine digit number rather than a phone number). I don't want to do another pattern search for efficiency reasons. Is there any way to accommodate this information in the regex pattern itself.

Comment: See the following section of Dive into Python: http://www.diveinto.org/python3/regular-expressions.html#phonenumbers

Comment: Not sure why you accepted the answer that you did, considering that mine is much simpler and just as correct.  No big, deal, just a little confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
pattern = r'(\(?(\d{3})\)?(?P<A>-)?(\d{3})(?(A)-?|-)(\d{4}))'
```

Using it:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(pattern)
check = ['123-333-1111', '(123)111-2222', '123-2221111', '1232221111']
for number in check:
    match = regex.match(number)
    print number, bool(match)
    if match:
        # show the numbers
        print 'nums:', filter(lambda x: x and x.isalnum(), match.groups())

>>> 
123-333-1111 True
nums: ('123', '333', '1111')
(123)111-2222 True
nums: ('123', '111', '2222')
123-2221111 True
nums: ('123', '222', '1111')
1232221111 False
```

---

**Note:**

You requested an explanation of: `(?P<A>-)` and `(?(A)-?|-)`

- `(?P<A>-)`   : Is a named capture group with the name `A`, `(?P<NAME> ... )`
- `(?(A)-?|-)` : Is a group that checks if the named group `A` captured something or not, if so it does the YES, else it does the NO capture. `(?(NAME)YES|NO)`

All this can be easily learned if you do a simple `help(re)` in the Python interpreter, or a Google search for Python Regular Expressions....

Comment: Can you please eloburate how this regex work specially (?P<A>-) and (?(A)-?|-) portion

Comment: Added a note. Please consult your documentation next time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following regex:

```
regex = r'(?:\d{3}-|\(\d{3}\))\d{3}-?\d{4}'
```

assuming that `(123)1112222` is acceptable.

The `|` acts as an or, and `\(` and `\)` escape `(` and `)`, respectively.

Comment: A question to OP, should 123456-7890 matches?

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
phoneRegex = re.compile("(\({0,1}[\d]{3}\)(?=[\d]{3})|[\d]{3}-)([\d]{3}[-]{0,1}[\d]{4})")
numbers = ["123-333-1111", "(123)111-2222", "123-2221111", "1232221111", "(123)-111-2222"]
for number in numbers:
    print bool(re.match(phoneRegex, number))
```

**Output**

```
True
True
True
False
False
```

You can see an explanation to this regular expression here : http://regex101.com/r/bA4fH8